Recursive use of ProcessPoolExecutor is Hanging
Problem
I'm trying to use a ProcessPoolExecutor with recursive calls, but it doesn't work. I created a minimal example below
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from time import sleep

executor = ProcessPoolExecutor()
i = 3

def test():
    global i
    print("top")
    if i == 0:
        print("bar")
        return
    else:
        print("foo")
        i -= 1
        p = executor.submit(test)
        print(p.result())
        print(i)

test()

What I would expect to happen is that i is decremented, a recursive call is made in the process pool, and then we wait for the result. This happens recursively until i hits 0, at which point the calls cascade back. However, this does not happen. I see the following output
top
foo
top
foo

at which point it hangs
Possible Issues
Race Condition
I figured it could be a race condition and i was not getting decremented every time, but this shouldn't matter, because the function should get called however many times
Global State
I removed the dependence on Global state by making the recursive calls happen with some random probability. It still hangs after two calls.
Edit: I am on Ubuntu 23

Your mental model for how things work here is mismatched with reality in several ways. This stuff is subtle at first!
I'm not going to write a small book, though. Let's start with some basics. First, use an if __name__ == "__main__": guard as the docs recommend. You're jumping in at the deep end by skipping it. When you're expert you can skip a life preserver, but before then you're most likely to sink ;-)
Second, nothing is shared "by magic" across processes. Since you're running on a Linux-y system, under the covers calling ProcessPoolExecutor() calls fork(), and the worker processes it creates get a copy of the calling process's state as of the time ProcessPoolExecutor() is called. Changes made to variable bindings in one process have no effect whatsoever on the bindings other processes see. global (or lack thereof) has nothing to do with this.
So study this much simpler code first until those points sink in:
i = 3

def test():
    print(f"i in test {i}")
    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
    executor = ProcessPoolExecutor() # all workers will see i==3
    i -= 1 # has no effect on workers
    print(f"i in main {i}")
    p = executor.submit(test)
    print(f"result {p.result()}")

which displays
i in main 2
i in test 3
result None

for reasons already explained.
